# Use middle mouse button to pan around (system wide)

Tags: mouse, touchpad

I've started working on Ubuntu machine in office, but for several last years I've used and still use MacBook Pro with macOS Sierra, and I really miss best trackpad ever that you can find on all Apple notebooks and magic trackpad it self, and now need to work with mouse.

I already made my Ubuntu as close as possible to macOS environment (at least Dock is available with Plank and Spotlight with Albert), but I wanted to extend a little bit more.

I need an option when I click and hold middle mouse button, webpages and text editors (like Sublime Text) could scroll in that direction where I point. I guess something like this you can do in Photoshop or Blender, but I need it system wide, to simulate great trackpad features. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it system-wide unfortunately. It is on an application per application basis.

Please note that the feature you are asking for is called **autoscrolling**. So googling `autoscrolling + <application name>` should help you find which application allows this feature.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the tip. More or less I need to rebuild my Ubuntu vocabulary :)